# How do I remove a directory from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, version

I have a folder in `vendor/plugins/` that I deleted and committed as a delete in my github. But the folder still exists on github.

How do I remove it from github as well? This..may be a submodule.. I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `git rm -rf vendor/plugins` to recursively delete it. You will need to commit this again.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
git rm -r vendor/plugins
git commit -m "Your comment here"
git push -u origin master
```

First deletes your directory
Second makes your commit
Third push your changes

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm -rf --cached $FILES
```

e.g. `git rm --cached -r .idea`

I have found this blog helpful when I wanted to remove some unnecessary hidden directories.

https://danielmiessler.com/blog/removing-files-from-a-git-repository-without-actually-deleting-them/